# How do I reference a value in a nested array in PHP?

Tags: php, sub-array

In PHP how to I return the value 1, 2 and 3 in the array bellow?

```
$tmpArray =
   array(
       array("one", array(1, 2, 3)),
       array("two", array(4, 5, 6)),
       array("three", array(7, 8, 9)
   )
);
```

Comment: read **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**

Comment: @MarkoD Great except it fails to provide an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Of course you could return the value of the index+1 from the array, but is that really the question?

Comment: If you have any influence in the structure of that array, I'd suggest to make it into an associative array; `$tmpArray = array('one' => array(1, 2, 3), 'two' => array(4, 5, 6));`. You can then simply access each via `$tmpArray['one'];` etc.

Comment: @thaJeztah Thanks, that would make more sense but unfortunately I am not allowed to do it.

Comment: For future reference - please consider [searching first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+nested+array) - with the correct terminology in your title, there are hundreds of suitable questions to learn from.

Comment: @klick.klonk clear, just checking if there were other (better/easier) possibilities for your problem

Comment: "not allowed to do it" ? wut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tmpArray[0][1] = array(1, 2, 3)
$tmpArray[0][1][0] = 1
$tmpArray[0][1][1] = 2
$tmpArray[0][1][2] = 3
```

Comment: I obviously didn't get this question at all. I thought klick klonk wanted to return the values of the array, and not set them.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: I'm not setting them either... I mean, I am (if you ignore the missing `;`) but the point here is to show the equality between the indexes (index - 1) and not the assignment operation.

Comment: aah ok :-) But I missunderstood the question anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
foreach($tmpArray as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $val)
       echo $val.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
foreach($tmpArray as $key => $value)
{
  if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $val)
      if(is_array($val){
        foreach($val as $v)
          echo $v."<br />";
      }
      else
        echo $val.'<br />';
  }
  else
      echo $value."<br />";
}
```